# What causes so big performance difference between two ways of building vector of static_vectors?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, boost

I wrote a benchmark for testing two ways of modifying and pushing a boost::container::static_vector to std::vector. They appear to perform in a strange way.

The first one:

```
typedef boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> Bar;

void foo(Bar& bar, std::vector<Bar>& bars)
{
    const auto oldSize = bar.size();
    bar.emplace_back(4);
    bars.emplace_back(bar);
    bar.resize(oldSize);
}
```

It modifies local version, copies it onto the vector, and then reverts local version to original state.

The second one:

```
typedef boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> Bar;

void foo(Bar& bar, std::vector<Bar>& bars)
{
    bars.emplace_back(bar);
    bars.back().emplace_back(4);
}
```

Instead of modifying and reverting local version, it simply modifies its copy directly on vector.

My reasoning is that `vector::emplace_back`s in both versions should perform equally well, as both just copy object of fixed size. Further, both of foo implementations call `static_vector::emplace_back` exactly once. The `resize` seems to be quite cheap. It should boil down to checking if `oldSize` is less than current `bar` size (it always is) and overwrite internal `bar` size variable. Clearly, there's no destructor call here. The second implentation calls instead `vector::back`, which addresses heap memory.

All in all, I expected both versions to be equally performant, maybe even with slight first version advantage (seeing it addresses heap memory only once, contrary to the second one). Yet, simple benchmark shows completely other results.

Benchmark:

```
std::vector<Bar> bars;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    bars.clear();
    Bar bar = {5, 6, 7};
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; ++j)
        foo(bar, bars);
}
```

First:

```
real    0m8,044s
user    0m7,846s
sys     0m0,152s
```

Second:

```
real    0m5,754s
user    0m5,559s
sys     0m0,184s
```

The question is, where does this tremendous difference come from?

Strangely, changing `static_vector` capacity seems to dimnish this gap. E.g.

```
typedef boost::container::static_vector<int, 16> Bar;
```

evens out any time difference. Why does the small `static_vector` capacity discriminate so much between these two ways, even though bigger ones seem to be unaffected by this issue?

I use g++ 8.3.0 with flags `-Ofast -std=c++17 -flto`.

EDIT:

Here's a little longer benchmark with bigger `static_vector` capacity (8):

```
std::vector<Bar> bars;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    bars.clear();
    Bar bar = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; ++j)
        foo(bar, bars);
}
```

`1m42,282s` vs `1m31,387s` still shows similar difference. Indeed, the first implementation could get away with explanation that it just copies more bytes. But then the question is, why similar benchmark with capacity raised to 16 shows a mere `2m46,733s` vs `2m45,128s`. I'd expect to see the same 11s difference.

Comment: As a first, you may want to consider the warmup of CPU:s. Timing a sillly-short program is pointless. A modern CPU goes from "waiting to get some" to "full speed ahead" very fast. It also winds down really fast. Your test tests nothing. Keep the pressure on - what's the thruput? Results / s if you will.

Comment: The first version copies 25% more bytes between different memory locations.

Comment: *"maybe even with slight first version advantage"*. For me, a priori, second one would be faster as it done less job (write 4 only once).

Comment: I also prefer second implementation as it allow to pass `bar` with const reference :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Bigger benchmarks show the same results, just scaled up. Besides, it still does not explain the equal performance of higher `static_vector` capacity implementations.

Comment: "Bigger benchmarks show the same results, just scaled up" - well that's fantastic. Bringing "8,044s" to the table isn't worth much though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have to recognize that the two methods are not actually equivalent. Let's call them `fooA` and `fooB`.

```
typedef boost::container::static_vector<int, 4> Bar;

void fooA(Bar& bar, std::vector<Bar>& bars)
{
    const auto oldSize = bar.size();
    bar.emplace_back(4);
    bars.emplace_back(bar);
    bar.resize(oldSize);
}

void fooB(Bar& bar, std::vector<Bar>& bars)
{
    bars.emplace_back(bar);
    bars.back().emplace_back(4);
}
```

#### Examining `fooA`

when we call `fooA`, the following things happen:

- We get the size of `bar`
- We *try* appending `4` to the end of `bar`. If that fails, an exception is thrown, and the function exits without anything being added to `bars`. `bar` may be left in an invalid state.
- `bar` is copied into `bars`
- `bar` is returned to it's original state.

#### Examining `fooB`

`fooB` has the same behavior in the success case, but *different behavior* in the failure case.

- We copy `bar` into `bars`
- We try appending `4` to the new vector at the end of `bars`. If this fails, an exception is thrown, and the function exits (but there IS something appended to the end of `bars`). `bar` is never in an invalid state, because it's never changed.

#### What does this mean?

The behavior of `fooA` and `fooB` is the same in the success case (no exception), but **they differ in behavior when an exception is thrown.** As a result, the compiler *cannot* apply the same optimizations to both of them, and it *cannot* remove behavior like the `resize`. This results in `fooB` being faster.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. But the second part of the original question remains unaswered: Why doesn't the optimization or lack of thereof discriminate between implementations working on `static_vector`s of higher capacity?